# Is it possible to disable a theme programmatically?

Tags: plugins, themes, hooks

I'm building a plugin that loads iframes to display some content.
I have specific scripts & styles for that content and would thus like to ignore the active theme when loading those templates; both to save loading time & to avoid CSS conflicts.

I know it is possible to [dequeue all scripts & styles](https://gelwp.com/articles/removing-all-enqueued-and-default-css-scripts-in-wordpress/) using the *wp_enqueue_scripts* and *wp_enqueue_scripts* hooks.

Thing is, as my plugin do also queue some scripts and styles, it would be cleaner to find a way to disable the current theme uphill rather than to quibble to unload some files and not others.

SO: is it possible to ignore / unload the current theme on certain pages / templates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is no specialized hook for this. However the hook `switch_theme` should work for you.

```
/**
 * Switches current theme to new template and stylesheet names.
 *
 * @since unknown
 * @uses do_action() Calls 'switch_theme' action on updated theme display name.
 *
 * @param string $template Template name
 * @param string $stylesheet Stylesheet name.
 */
function switch_theme($template, $stylesheet) {
    update_option('template', $template);
    update_option('stylesheet', $stylesheet);
    delete_option('current_theme');
    $theme = get_current_theme();
    do_action('switch_theme', $theme);
}
```

So you should write custom function that deactivate the theme via hook and activate back, if your done with your task.

```
add_action('switch_theme', function($theme){
    if ( 'Your_Theme_Name' == $theme )
    {
        // do something.
    }

    // do others.

    return;
});
```